# Time Format in Excel (:) not appearing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want my time in excel to be hh:mm:ss. But all the formats i found for every country in the format cell > number > time > location is hh.mm.ss
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you want your time **displayed** as `hh:mm:ss`?  Or do you want to be able to **enter** your time as `hh:mm:ss`?  If the latter, you will need to either change your windows regional settings for time; or use VBA or use a formula with different column for entering and displaying your data.  If the former, then you can create a custom number format as outlined by @teylyn

Answer (score 6):

The notation of the time and the date format default depends on your regional settings, which is a Windows setting, not an Excel setting. Check your Windows settings.

You can of course create any time format you like with a custom format. Try

hh:mm:ss

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.